# Azure IoT Adge BLE Module - Implementation of BLE for linux container

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, docker-container, azure-iot-edge

I'm trying to implement module that receive and send messages from/to Bluetooth device.

I was looking for a NuGet package that could search, connect and send messages through Bluetooth but I could not find anything for Linux.

I'm using .NET Core 2.1 and C#.

Answer (score 0):

I do see that this is [Ble.Net](https://github.com/nexussays/ble.net/blob/master/Readme.md) is supported with .NET Standard 2.0 so you should be able to use it on Linux. Worth a Try !!!!

Comment: Linux not supported by this package.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample BLE module for Edge here: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/tree/master/edge-modules/edge-ble
It is written in JS, though. But may be worth a try.